# Can I use "Windows Server Backup function" or "wbadmin" to backup MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, database-backup, windows-server-backup

I am making a backup strategy for MariaDB on Windows Server.

To make my life easier, I was wondering if I can use the "Windows Server Backup function" or "wbadmin" as a backup tool for MariaDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but I doubt it will make your life easier. `wbadmin` isn't a general backup tool applicable to everything, and in addition to that databases often have specially designed backup procedures. For example, `wbadmin` [isn't inteded as a tool to backup even for Microsoft's own SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/543515/how-can-i-backup-an-sql-server-database-using-windows-server-backup).

First is to think about how you are going to restore from these backups and what else you might want to do. Then, please, read this carefully: [Backup and Restore Overview](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backup-and-restore-overview/#filesystem-snapshots).

The backup must follow this procedure:

1. Connect to MariaDB and lock tables: `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`. Don't disconnect, this session must survive at least until step 3.
2. Start a backup using `wbadmin`.
3. When VSS service finishes making a shadow copy, you can quit session started at the step 1, releasing a lock.

Steps 1 and 3 are essential.

Comment: Thanks. Shutdown MariaDB and do the backup is another option, isn't it?

Comment: Of course. Usually people want to do backups "without service disruption". If you can afford stopping a service, you can really do absolutely any method to back up its files.